# Broadcast receiver not working when app is cleared from RAM

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I am new to android. I am making an alarm clock. Its working perfectly until the user clears the app from the RAM. On searching, I found that broadcast receivers don't work if the app is cleared from the RAM. So, what exactly should I do? Will sending the broadcast from a service help? Also if you have a link to a good tutorial to Services in android, pls do share. Also let me know if there is some other way to solve my problem.

Comment: Which phone are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing on Xiaomi mi4

Comment: Now I tested it on OnePlus X. It works even if the RAM is cleared on this device. Then I tested it on Le1s, again the app doesn't work if its cleared from RAM. Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: Xiaomi has customized Android features which is device specific. Check my answer below for the solution. I wish it helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Xiaomi** devices, you just have to add your app to **Autostart** list, to do so, follow these simple steps given below:

- Open **Security** app on your phone.
- Tap on **Permissions**, it'll show you two options: Autostart and
  Permissions
- Tap on **Autostart**, it'll show you list of apps with on or off toggle
  buttons.
- Turn on toggle of your app, you're done!

Comment: It worked! but whenever i restart the phone, it agains takes away the autostart permission from the app. How to give it the permission permanently?

Comment: I checked it on my Xiaomi Redmi 1s, it doesn't take away the permission, it's still there in autostart list. You'll have to manage the restart using a boot broadcast receiver.

Comment: @Sidhartha We cannot automate this workaround, it is device specific settings. You must guide your app users what to do (just like permissions) to get your app running well in their devices.

Comment: @zeeali other application like alarm is working without this kind of setup ,they would be adding some permission !!

Answer (score 0):

You can register broadcast receivers either inside the activity at runtime or in the manifest.  You want to adopt the latter approach

Comment: The receiver is declared in the manifest. But still the receiver doesn't work when the app is cleared from the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have similar problems with AlarmManager, AlarmReceivers and this kind of things. There are some tips that can help you in your code:

1. Make sure that you are scheduling your alarm correctly.
2. Make sure that you are setting the propers permissions on the manifest.
3. Take care if the device is locked or it was rebooted.

There is a quite useful tutorial that helps me to control and make a "Hello World!" example with AlarmManager: [AlarmManager Repeating Example](http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android#7-download-source-code)

Note: In API 19 and higher, the method **setRepeating** is not exactly (maybe the alarm triggers at 10:00 or at 10:15), so you must use **setExact**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The alarm is working perfectly until n unless the user explicitly clears it from the ram. So, I assume that there needs to be a service that is to be used so that somehow the receiver keeps working in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can register broadcast receiver in two ways

```
1. From your activity.

2. From your manifest.
```

if you registered broadcast throught activity, It wont receive after your activity is destroyed, So thats is where we register **`BroadcastReceiver`** in manifest.

This link will help you [BroadcastReceiver](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)

Comment: Yes, I had registered it in manifest. The alarm doesnt work if the application is cleared from the RAM by the user from the multitasking window. If the alarm is present on the RAM, it works perfectly well.