# AlarmManager is not executing the class in time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In my project I want to change a flag value in SharedPreference in particular time every day ,I have implemented the AlarmManager but It is not performing the task .
My function to call my receiver class :

```
public void changeAttendaceFlag(){
        Log.d(TAG,"changeAttendaceFlag !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,10);
        Intent activateLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Attendance.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),101,activateLogin,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
    }
```

My receiver class :

```
public class Attendance extends BroadcastReceiver {
    FcmSession fcmSession;
    private static final String TAG = "Attendance";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, " Attendance Called !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fcmSession = new FcmSession(context);
        fcmSession.store_dialog_value(true);
        UtilsMethods utilsMethods = new UtilsMethods();
        String time = utilsMethods.getCurrentDateAndTime();
        Log.d(TAG,"change attendance flag  :"+time);
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you put this code? in a service?

Comment: @SecretCoder In my launcher activity (LoginActivity)

Comment: did you close the app and wait for the time?

Comment: @SecretCoder Yes .

Comment: ow, thats the reason why it wont perform the task. when your task is in your Activity and when you close it, the instance of that activity will be destroyed. In order to retain the instance you should implement it inside your background service. the background service wont lose its instance even if you close the app. Refer here on how to start creating a service https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: alaram manager set() and setRepeat functions are not accurate , it may give u lag of 1 to 3 minutes , you should wait for at least 1 to 3 minutes. If you want ur alarm to ring at exact time then you should setExact() method and handle repeat logic Attendance class. You can set another alarm is attendance class for next day. But setExact added in api level 19. refer to link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: @SecretCoder Can you please share some other link .

Comment: here https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/01/android-service-tutorial-2.html. just copy paste what you see here and transfer your Pending Intent code here. Run the function on `onStartCommand`. Remember to put correct onStart command (eg. START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY)

Comment: @SecretCoder from onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) I am calling my function ,but how to use "onStart command (eg. START_STICKY, START_NOT_STICKY" ,actually I don't understand this part.

Comment: Have you put the `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest? Is it ever getting called?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **Inexact** instead of just simple **Repeating** for targetSdk greater than 19 API.
Check **Note** at this [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

So, Change and try with below line:-

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

**Updated:**

Also, In some phone devices(like **Xiaomi**, **Lenovo**) app needs to put in **AutoStart** list. For reference answer check this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36785799/7806873)

Comment: Once the application is cleared from the background it is not working .

Comment: @Sidhartha In which device are you testing?

Comment: @Sidhartha See that some device needs settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36785799/7806873

Comment: ya this problem I am facing while testing in lenovo k5 vive and xiome phones.Is there any proper solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is just part of the answer. Here is how you implement the service `onStartCommand`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // this is where you run your changeAttendaceFlag() method
    return START_STICKY; // this will make your service recreate when your app is closed
}
```

The following return type will be available once your class extends `Service`

> **START_STICKY** : Using this return value will make your service recreate when you close your app. When you force close your app the service will recreated but the intent wont be redeliver therefore the service will always run without doing anything.
>
> **START_NOT_STICKY** : Using this return value will make your service not recreate when closed.
>
> **START_REDELIVER_INTENT** : Using this return value will make your service function similar to START_STICKY but this time when theres an intent, it will redeliver it.

**Note**: Data will be reinstantiate once app is closed since the service will be recreated. Save your data in **SharedPreferences** or **SQLite DB**.

For autostart, you can do that in settings but when you restart your phone, it will disable autostart and you need to enable it which is a really bad user experience(I think this is for some phone). You can do autostart on your service as well by implementing a `BroadcastReceiver` for **BOOT_COMPLETED**. Here is a great example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4562747/5870896